# Group by is returning first instance of value rather than grouping

Tags: sql, group-by

```
SELECT userid, 
    Round((totalhold - playercomps - freemoney - (depositmade_amt*.1)),2) as SpecValue, txndate

FROM player_activity

WHERE userid = 2026939

GROUP BY month(txndate)
```

Ideally I would be calculating this user's value for each month. However, instead my query just returns the first value for each month. For example, if June had 3 SpecValues (10, 20, 30), my query only returns the first SpecValue (10).

Help?

Comment: You should add your DBMS to the tags. (my guess: mysql)

Comment: @eddd83 Wildplasser is most likely right...this is MySQL, any other database would have returned an error.  Think about your grouping logic...You are asking to display the txndate but group by month(txndate).  If the txndate had 2016/07/08, 2016/07/19, 2016/07/28...what date would you expect it to return in the select statement when you are grouping them by month?  Take a look into aggregates and why this logic won't work (in this case, mysql is randomly taking a value from txndate...any other database would return an error...mysql likes doing the wrong thing when it can)

Comment: @eddd83 - Also...your userID isn't included in the group by statement.  Are you wanting the results to be grouped by user, or do you want mysql to randomly return a userid for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userid, 
    Sum(Round((totalhold - playercomps - freemoney - (depositmade_amt*.1)),2)) as SpecValue, txndate

FROM player_activity

WHERE userid = 2026939

GROUP BY month(txndate)
```

Comment: right idea with the sum() function included, but the select and group by logic here doesn't work.